# Why size_t in cpp is named 'size_t'?

Tags: c++, c

I mean, what does the character `t` in size_t mean?

This question had occured to me years ago when I was learning cpp for the first time. Why the designer of this language chooses to use this character rather than `size_i`, `size_n`, `size_l`, etc.? I'm thinking about it's the abbreviation of `int`, but not sure if there's a better answer.

Comment: I have always assumed it stood for `type`.

Comment: Yes, it stands for `type`. All the names that end in `_t` are typedefs.